# Bounding a real integral involving complex constant

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis

Is this integral finite $$|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-i\pi x^2}\ dx|$$

can we use the fact that $e^{-\pi x^2}$ have compact support to estimate the above integral?

Comment: $e^{-\pi x^2}$ does *not* have compact support.

Comment: The integral is finite, just change variable to $y = x^2$ and apply the "improper integral" version of [Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test).

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a way for you to solve it, but I know this:

$$ e^{ix} = cos(x) + i\, sin(x) $$
So:
$$ e^{i \pi x^2} = cos(\pi x^2) + i\, sin(\pi x^2) $$

And since the limits of the sin cosin funtions towards infinit are indefenid, I have to conclude that this integral has no solution.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

I hope I have helped, Saclyr.

EDIT:

Check this, it corrected my assumption:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e^{i+\pi+x^2}+from+-infinite+to+infinite

Answer (score 0):

Your integral is a slight variation of the [improper Fresnel integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral).